# Xcode 6.0.1 No Completion and highlighting

Tags: xcode

After installing Xcode 6.0.1 there's no real code completion and the code highlighting (i.e. 'navigationController') anymore.

Code and completion looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i have tried many things and i found a solution.
You need go to **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/** and **delete all** folders and files.
Delete DerivedData from organizer not helps. Just manual deleting.